# SQL CHECK CONSTRAINT USING LIKE and OR

Tags: sql, sql-server

I keep receiving the following message on SQL Server 2018.

Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'OR'.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_owners(
ownerID     INT IDENTITY(10001,1) PRIMARY KEY,

lastName    NVARCHAR(30)  NOT NULL,

firstName   NVARCHAR(30)  NOT NULL,

address     NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,

postcode    NVARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL,

telno       NVARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL CHECK (telno LIKE '0%' OR '44%' OR '353%')
);
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2018** version - we have 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017 and 2019 - take your pick

Answer (score 2):

It would be just like any other use of `LIKE` in a boolean expression.  You need to repeat the full expression:

```
telno NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL CHECK
     (telno LIKE '0%' OR telno LIKE '44%' OR telno LIKE '353%')
```